# Update RecyclerView in a fragment from another fragment onClick

Tags: android, onclick, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a ViewPager with two Fragments with RecyclerViews that show Locations and Items. Each location contains different items. Now I want to update the recyclerView inside ItemsFragment when a location is selected in LocationsFragment. I set onClick method to location element to update the `activeLocation` field but I don't know how to refresh the data in `items' recyclerView`.

I would need to supply a new `List` object I get from `getItems()` into the adapter, but the adapter is null whenever `ItemsFragment` loses focus or make it so the fragment is recreated every time the activeLocation changes.

The only time it refreshes now is when the ItemsFragment's `onCreateView` is called. The list updates, because a new `ItemAdapter` is created and `getItems()` is called inside constructor. But this only happens when I scroll to 4th tab and back, so that the `itemsFragment` (2nd) is cleared from memory and reloaded.

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements     MaterialTabListener {
MaterialTabHost tabHost;
ViewPager pager;
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
private final int[] icons = {R.drawable.icon_locations, R.drawable.icon_items};
public static Location activeLocation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build());
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    activeLocation = realm.where(Location.class).findFirst();
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabHost = (MaterialTabHost) this.findViewById(R.id.materialTabHost);

    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
        tabHost.addTab(
                tabHost.newTab()
                        .setIcon(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), icons[i], null)).setTabListener(this)
        );
    }

}
```

ViewPager:

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final String[] TITLES = {"Locations", "Items"};

    private final int[] ICONS = {R.drawable.icon_locations, R.drawable.icon_items};


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case FragmentType.LOCATIONS: {
                fragment = LocationsFragment.newInstance();
                break;
            }
            case FragmentType.ITEMS: {
                fragment = ItemsFragment.newInstance();
                break;
            }
        }
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

LocationsFragment:

```
public class LocationsFragment extends Fragment {

   private RecyclerView recyclerView;

   private LocationAdapter adapter;

public static LocationsFragment newInstance() {
    return new LocationsFragment();
}

public LocationsFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_locations, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.locations_recycler_view);
    adapter = new LocationAdapter(getActivity(), getLocations());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    return layout;
}

public List<Location> getLocations() {
    List<Location> locations;
    Log.d("null act", getActivity() == null? "null" : "not null");
    Realm realm =  Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    locations = realm.where(Location.class).findAll();

    return locations;
}


}
```

LocationAdapter:

```
public class LocationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LocationAdapter.LocationHolder> {

List<Location> list = Collections.emptyList();
Context context;

private LayoutInflater inflater;

public LocationAdapter(Context context, List<Location> list) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public LocationHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_location, parent, false);
    return new LocationHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final LocationHolder holder, int position) {


    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("clicked", "Location " + location.getId() + " " + location.getName() + " pressed");
            if (context instanceof MainActivity) {
                MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) context;
                MainActivity.activeLocation = location;
                mainActivity.setFragment(1);  //this changes the title on actionBar and tab highlights
            }
        }
    });
}
```

`ItemsFragment` and `ItemAdapter` are the same as Locations.

Comment: Provide methods, to send adapter from first fragment to second one and to update data in the adapter, call notifyDataSetChanged there or one of the notify(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) methods

Comment: @CullyCross I tried doing something similar by getting a reference to the adapter and notyfying, but I got nullpointer exception whenever ItemsFragment was not focused. I found a working way to do it by using a static `List` inside itemAdapter and static method in itemsFragment to refresh it, but I don't really like it, it's more of a workaround than actual solution

Comment: Ah, try to do that with this steps:
1) with onClick save some data needed to update list 
2) create new fragment with this data in the bundle
3) retrieve this data and make list based on this data
4) switch page to it